# How to apply rolling function where time is in relative weeks not a time stamp and apply group by

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, rolling-computation

I'd like to apply rolling function to a data frame which is not indexed by datestamps but by relative weeks after start of experiment.
As an example this is my starting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 20,'Val_2':0.6,'Val_3':40,'TimeofDay':'MORN'}
,{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 40,'Val_2':0.9,'Val_3':27,'TimeofDay':'NOON'}
,{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 24,'Val_2':0.65,'Val_3':44,'TimeofDay':'EVE'}
,{'RelWeek': 4, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 25,'Val_2':0.34,'Val_3':55,'TimeofDay':'MORN'}
,{'RelWeek': 4, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 21,'Val_2':0.61,'Val_3':34,'TimeofDay':'NOON'}
,{'RelWeek': 4, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 25,'Val_2':0.67,'Val_3':21,'TimeofDay':'EVE'}
,{'RelWeek': 5, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 20,'Val_2':0.6,'Val_3':40,'TimeofDay':'MORN'}
,{'RelWeek': 5, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': np.nan,'Val_2':np.nan,'Val_3': np.nan,'TimeofDay':'NOON'}
,{'RelWeek': 5, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 25,'Val_2':0.68,'Val_3':48,'TimeofDay':'EVE'}
,{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 20,'Val_2':0.6,'Val_3':40,'TimeofDay':'MORN'}
,{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 33, 'Val_1': 40,'Val_2':0.9,'Val_3':27,'TimeofDay':'NOON'}
,{'RelWeek': 2, 'id': 34, 'Val_1': 24,'Val_2':0.65,'Val_3':44,'TimeofDay':'EVE'}
,{'RelWeek': 2, 'id': 34, 'Val_1': 25,'Val_2':0.34,'Val_3':55,'TimeofDay':'MORN'}
,{'RelWeek': 2, 'id': 34, 'Val_1': 21,'Val_2':0.61,'Val_3':34,'TimeofDay':'NOON'}
,{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 34, 'Val_1': 25,'Val_2':0.67,'Val_3':21,'TimeofDay':'EVE'}
,{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 34, 'Val_1': 20,'Val_2':0.6,'Val_3':40,'TimeofDay':'MORN'}
,{'RelWeek': 3, 'id': 34, 'Val_1': 25,'Val_2':0.68,'Val_3':48,'TimeofDay':'EVE'}])

df

    RelWeek TimeofDay  Val_1  Val_2  Val_3  id
0         3      MORN   20.0   0.60   40.0  33
1         3      NOON   40.0   0.90   27.0  33
2         3       EVE   24.0   0.65   44.0  33
3         4      MORN   25.0   0.34   55.0  33
4         4      NOON   21.0   0.61   34.0  33
5         4       EVE   25.0   0.67   21.0  33
6         5      MORN   20.0   0.60   40.0  33
7         5      NOON    NaN    NaN    NaN  33
8         5       EVE   25.0   0.68   48.0  33
9         3      MORN   20.0   0.60   40.0  33
10        3      NOON   40.0   0.90   27.0  33
11        2       EVE   24.0   0.65   44.0  34
12        2      MORN   25.0   0.34   55.0  34
13        2      NOON   21.0   0.61   34.0  34
14        3       EVE   25.0   0.67   21.0  34
15        3      MORN   20.0   0.60   40.0  34
16        3       EVE   25.0   0.68   48.0  34
```

> I want to do 3 things now
>
> > 1. groupby('id' ,Timeof Day')
> > 2. Take the max and min 'RelWeek for each id and iterate over RelWeek. It is important to note that  relative week  is different for each id .  Implement a rolling function for Window= 3 or ( a flexible number) over Range of min to max Iter value
> > 3. the output of the rolling function should appear as - "Original column name_TimeofDay_function'(By function I mean the aggregate function applied to rolling window,  for e.g  Min, Max, Stdev, Mean etc )

**OUTPUT** : (Below is just how  an ideal output should look like.The numbers are just dummy numbers right now and don't reflect actual mean or stdev etc. The names of the columns really reflect of what the content of the column should be . Any alternate way of output as long as it gives me the information for the above requirements also works

```
Output_df

      Val_1_EVE_Mean  Val_1_EVE_Stdev  Val_1_MORN_Mean  Val_1_MORN_Stdev  \
0            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
1            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
2            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
3            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
4            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
5            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   

      Val_1_NOON_Mean  Val_1_NOON_Stdev  Val_2_EVE_Mean  Val_2_EVE_Stdev  \
0             33.6              33.6            24.6             24.6   
1             33.6              33.6            24.6             24.6   
2             33.6              33.6            24.6             24.6   
3             33.6              33.6            24.6             24.6   
4             33.6              33.6            24.6             24.6   
5             33.6              33.6            24.6             24.6   

   Val_2_MORN_Mean  Val_2_MORN_Stdev  Val_2_NOON_Mean  Val_2_NOON_Stdev  \
0             0.51              0.51             33.6              33.6   
1             0.51              0.51             33.6              33.6   
2             0.51              0.51             33.6              33.6   
3             0.51              0.51             33.6              33.6   
4             0.51              0.51             33.6              33.6   
5             0.51              0.51             33.6              33.6   

      Val_3_EVE_Mean  Val_3_EVE_Stdev  Val_3_MORN_Mean  Val_3_MORN_Stdev  \
0            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
1            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
2            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
3            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
4            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   
5            24.6             24.6             21.6              21.6   

   Val_3_NOON_Mean  Val_3_NOON_Stdev     Window  id  
0             33.6              33.6  [3, 4, 5]  33  
1             33.6              33.6  [4, 5, 6]  33  
2             33.6              33.6  [5, 6, 7]  33  
3             33.6              33.6  [2, 3, 4]  34  
4             33.6              33.6  [3, 4, 5]  34  
5             33.6              33.6  [4, 5, 6]  34
```

Thanks in advance to the experts who can give me some direction in this

Comment: This question is probably too broad. I would start reorganizing your dataframe so that the RelWeek is the only index item and everything else is in the column, i.e. `df2 = df.groupby(['id', 'RelWeek', 'TimeofDay']).mean().unstack(['id', 'TimeofDay'])`. Note that the data had some duplicate entries for id, RelWeek and TimeofDay (e.g. rows 0 & 9), so I first grouped on these and took the mean. Then you can just perform the rolling mean on `RelWeek`: `df2.rolling(window=2).mean()`

Comment: @Alexander Thank you . your suggestion really helped me . It was a very simple solution but I was able to tweak it to achieve my goal